# hyperbolic sector area is invariant under transformation

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

I want to prove, that area of the hyperbolic sector is invariant under tranformation of the form:

$f((x,y)) = (sx, \frac{y}{s})$, where $s$ is arbitrary positive number. Let's find the area, it should be equal to integral $A=\int_{a}^{b} \frac{1}{x} dx = \ln{\frac{a}{b}}$. Then $\ln{\frac{sa}{sb}} = \ln{\frac{a}{b}}$. Am I correct? It confuses me that I didn’t use the condition for the second coordinate in any way here.

[image]

Comment: Do you know the formula for change of variables in integral of a function of several variables? If you do, think about the determinant of your linear transformation.

Comment: @MoisheKohan can you please explaine it in more details?

Comment: If you do not know the change of variables formula, I cannot help you.

Comment: Your argument works, because $y'=1/x'$.